# What is the probability that $p > 0.6$ given that John flips a head

Tags: probability

> A coin is forged such that its probability of landing heads is random. That is, if the probability that the coin lands heads is $p$, $p$ is chosen uniformly and randomly on the interval $(0,1)$. John takes this coin and flips it, and it comes up heads. What is the probability that $p > 0.6$?
>
> Bonus: If John flips the coin twice, and gets heads both times, what is the probability that $p > 0.6$? What if he flips it $3$ times? Can you generalize? (Not sure if this is doable without calculus).

**Attempt**

This seems to be a conditional probability question that is asking, "What is the probability that $p > 0.6$ given that he flips a head." By conditional probability this is $$\dfrac{P(\text{flips heads and $p>0.6$)}}{P(\text{flips heads})}.$$
I am unsure what to do next.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think the questions means uniform.

Comment: Since the given is that he flipped a heads, shouldn't it be $P(\text{flips heads})$ in the denominator?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the distribution of $p$; since $p$ is uniform on $[0, 1]$, we can write

\begin{align}
P(p > 0.6 \mid \text{heads})
    & = \frac{P(p > 0.6, \text{heads})}{P(\text{heads})} \\
    & = \frac{\int_{p=0.6}^1 p \, dp}{\int_{p=0}^1 p \, dp} \\
    & = \frac{\left.\frac{p^2}{2}\right]_{p=0.6}^1}
             {\left.\frac{p^2}{2}\right]_{p=0}^1} \\
    & = \frac{1-0.36}{1-0} = 0.64
\end{align}

Comment: In general $P(a < p < b, \text{heads}) = \int_{p=a}^b p\,dp$.  This is essentially the sum (i.e., the integral), over all $p, a < p < b$, of the probability of heads, weighted by the distribution of $p$.  But $p$ itself is the probability of heads—that's why it's the integrand—and the distribution of $p$ is uniform; that is, the PDF of $p$ is just $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a picture.

You have an event where two independent uniform random numbers in $[0,1]$ are chosen: $p$ and $q$.

We interpret $q$ as "heads if $q<p$ and tails if $q>p$." So you want the ratio area of $A_1=\{(p,q)\mid p>0.6, q<p\}$ to the area of $A_2=\{(p,q)\mid q<p\}$.

Given that $A_1$ is a trapezoid, and $A_2$ is a triangle, they are fairly standard areas to compute.